# Why the background image is shaded and centered?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

This has to be merely with how the users will experience the site. Shaded content on the background is often used to indicate that you are on a different layer and once you are done
the information on the background will be visible and not shaded.

As it is centered only some of the edges of the images in the background are shown, which strengthens the idea that you are on a layer that is hiding you something.

User will often come and look for a close [x] button somewhere until they realize they are in the main content already.

Comment: Is this indeed a 'why' question or is this actually a request to change the background? - then please [edit]

Comment: It is both. I don't think its right, but it may have a good reason.